# How to store extra data into multi curl info handler?

Tags: php, curl

I'm having trouble finding more info about a particular curl handle in a multi curl scenario. Here is the code.

```
$job_count = 5;
 while ( $eachPr = $prList->fetch () ) {


            for ( $job_number = 1 ;
                        $job_number <= $job_count ;
                        $job_number ++ , $index ++ ) {


                $url = $this->getURL ( $eachPr[ "name" ] ,
                                       $eachPr[ "category" ] ) ;

                $this->log ( $url ) ;



                $curl_handle = curl_init () ;

                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_USERAGENT ,
                              $userAgent ) ;
                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_URL ,
                              $url ) ;
                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_FAILONERROR ,
                              TRUE ) ;
                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,
                              TRUE ) ;
                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER ,
                              TRUE ) ;
                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,
                              TRUE ) ;

                curl_setopt ( $curl_handle ,
                              CURLOPT_COOKIE ,
                              $cookie ) ;
                var_dump($curl_handle);

                /* add a request to the multiple handle */
                curl_multi_add_handle ( $multi_handler ,
                                        $curl_handle ) ;
                $eachPr = $prList->fetch () ;
            }


            do {
                while ( ($execrun = curl_multi_exec ( $multi_handler ,
                                                      $running )) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM )  ;
                if ( $execrun != CURLM_OK ) {
                    break ;
                }
                /* a request was just completed -- find out which one */
                while ( $done = curl_multi_info_read ( $multi_handler ) ) {

                    /* get the info and content returned on the request */
                    $info   = curl_getinfo ( $done[ 'handle' ] ) ;
                    $output = curl_multi_getcontent ( $done[ 'handle' ] ) ;
                    var_dump($info);
                    /* send the return values to the thread waiting to process the data . 
                    $this->work_pool[] = $this->submit ( new PrStacker ( $eachPr[ "name" ] ,
                                                                                        $eachPr[ "id" ] ,
                                                                                        $output ) ) ;

                    $this->work_pool[ count ( $this->work_pool ) - 1 ]->wait () ;


                    /* remove the curl handle that just completed */
                    curl_multi_remove_handle ( $multi_handler ,
                                               $done[ 'handle' ] ) ;


                }

                /* Block for data in / output; error handling is done by curl_multi_exec */
                if ( $running ) {
                    curl_multi_select ( $multi_handler ,
                                        30 ) ;
                }
            } while ( $running ) ;


            /* write the current index to the file */
            file_put_contents ( $symbols_index_file ,
                                $index ) ;

            $sleep_interval = rand ( 5 ,
                                     10 ) ;

            $this->log ( " Sleeping Now For " . $sleep_interval . "  seconds" ) ;

            sleep ( $sleep_interval ) ;

            $index ++ ;
        }
        curl_multi_close ( $multi_handler ) ;
```

So in here im looping through a list of 11K product using `while ( $eachPr = $prList->fetch () )`. Then taking 5 product at a time i'm initializing curl handles which i add to the curl multi handle.

The handles are executed at the do while loop. Here comes the trouble after selecting the request which was just done using `$done = curl_multi_info_read ( $multi_handler )` .
Each response is passed to another thread which handles other task. And each thread requires the product name, the product id and the raw html response. 
Here this is how each of the stackers are initialized

```
$this->work_pool[] = $this->submit ( new PrStacker ( $eachPr[ "name" ] ,
                                                                                            $eachPr[ "id" ] ,
                                                                                            $output ) ) ;
```

But after each of the curl requests gets done i can't find a way to send the correct product name and id which corresponds to the request that was finished. When in the above code i pass the name, id and output to the PrStacker thread i realized that it was not the correct product that corresponds to the request which was done. Its a  different and wrong product that gets passed to the threads.

So is there any way in which i can include the product name and id along with each of the curl handles/requests before it gets executed so that the program may recognize which response corresponds to which product. I hope my explanation can be understood.

Please let me know if there is any way in which this can be done.

Comment: I assume you could record each 'product detail' information with the associated 'curl handle' request as returned by 'curl_multi_info_read'. That way you know which reply goes with with 'product detail' request. The examples in the manual seem to be quite useful. i.e: [manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php)

Comment: Yes, but how do i record the product info with the associated curl handle. The link you provided of curl_multi_info_read just reads each handles after it gets done, i already use this function to get the response and the info. But how do i add that extra info to a curl handle. I mean is it possible at all.

Comment: Have a look at [The SplObjectStorage class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) which allows you to associate data with objects using the object as a key. Or store the product and CUrl Handle in an array with the Product Details using Spl_Object_Hash as the key.

Comment: Voila! It worked. I've used a map with the curl handle as a key and the product info as values. And now i can easily associate each handle with the corresponding product info. Can you post your reply in an answer so that i can accept it and mark this question as solved. Thanks a lot for your help really appreciate it.

Comment: Your welcome, glad it is all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is to associate two php 'objects' with each other. One is identified by a 'cUrl handle', the other is 'Product Details' which is a php object' or 'instance. The 'cUrl handle' will be used as the key in this case.

There are various ways of associating 'objects' together. The issue is that there are no 
'obvious keys' that can be used.

Still, PHP 'arrays' (hash maps) are very flexible data structures indeed. They can store any standard PHP object. The awkward part can be getting a useful 'key' to look them up again.

Here are some useful approaches that will work:

1) The SplObjectStorage class which allows you to associate data with objects using the object itself as a key. It is described, with examples: [class.splobjectstorage](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)

2) store the 'ProductDetails' object in an array, using the 'Spl_Object_Hash' of the 'cUrl Handle', as the key.

Answer (score 12):

Store private data inside the cURL easy handle, e.g. the product id:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, $this->getId());
// then later
$id = curl_getinfo($done['handle'], CURLINFO_PRIVATE);
```

This "private data" feature was not documented in the PHP manual until early 2015. It was introduced already in PHP 5.2.4. It allows you to store and retrieve a string of your choice inside the cURL handle. Use it for a key/ID that uniquely identifies the product, and that you can use to lookup the product in your own data structure.

See: [`curl_getinfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-getinfo.php) and [curl's Predefined Constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php).

Comment: Yes i had implemented a custom key/value pair for storing and retrieving product info in the curl requests.

Comment: Excelent! There are short descriptions of this feature here https://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php and here https://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: I don't believe the docs say this anywhere, however, the value associated with CURLOPT_PRIVATE must be represented as a string!  `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, new stdClass());` will shit its pants.